# How to retrieve String from jsonPath() in MockMvc

Tags: spring, mocking, jsonpath

I would like to compare if two jsonPath value are equal like this:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get(requestURL)).andExpect(jsonPath("$.prop1", equalTo(jsonPath("$.prop2"))));
```

but then my test was failed. The ***jsonPath("$.prop1")*** returned the correct value I want, but ***jsonPath("$.prop2")*** returned not the value of this property, instead the classname like:

> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers@7b7aaaf6

Can anyone give me idea how can I perform the ***toString()*** method for the jsonPath()? I did try also ***jsonPath("$.prop2").toString()*** but also received the classname.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get(requestURL)).andReturn();
String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

assertEquals(JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.prop1").toString(),JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.prop2").toString());
```

See [github readme](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for more details.